# rfkill: input handler disabled

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

When I start my Linux system (Debian/stable), I see that the last line of `dmesg` states:

```
[   44.043657] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[rfkill](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rfkill.txt) is a Linux kernel subsystem providing access to hardware and software toggle switches that enable or disable radio transmitters, such as wireless network cards and Bluetooth dongles. The Linux kernel contains an apparently deprecated functionality called `rfkill-input` that toggles an rfkill switch from inside the kernel in response to pressing a dedicated key on the keyboard (usually labelled with a radio transmitter icon). Userspace software that wants to take over handling such keypresses can disable this built-in functionality by opening `/dev/rfkill` and invoking `ioctl` with the command `RFKILL_IOC_NOINPUT`. When this happens, [the kernel emits the message mentioned in the question](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/rfkill/core.c?h=db54615e21419c3cb4d699a0b0aa16cc44d0e9da#n1280).

In other words, it’s harmless; it (probably) only means that some userspace software (for example your desktop environment) took over handling of the ‘disable radio’ key. Running `fuser /dev/rfkill` may help you discover which particular process it is.

You should expect that the message will disappear altogether in a future kernel version that removes `rfkill-input`, with the kernel expecting that userspace shall *always* be responsible for responding to such keypresses.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.10, this is caused by /usr/libexec/gsd-rfkill which is the gnome settings daemon. It's annoying that it does this, as my system has 0 wifi and 0 bluetooth devices.