# Can I stop NetworkManager from using my media key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, networkmanager, xbindkeys

I am on a Thinkpad 460S. There is a media key on the keyboard to cut the wifi via Rfkill (F8).

NetworkManager is grabbing the key and everytime it is pressed, disable or reenable the rfkill switch.

I dont want this to happen and I'd rather use this key in xbindkeys (not usable atm since it is grabbed by NetworkManager).

Is there a way to stop NetworkManager from doing that?

Comment: I think it's your desktop environment doing that. NetworkManager itself doesn't access the GUI. What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using i3 so I dont think it would do that? Furthermore I see a networkmanager event in journalctl when I press the button

Edit: Checked in my i3 config, I dont find any bindsym that would do this...

Comment: After further investigation, these days, systemd is the one that handles rfkill. And as you found out, that's routed from the kernel.

Comment: Would disabling systemd-rfkill.service and systemd-rfkill.socket be enough? I tried and it doesnt seem to work. Would you have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a (deprecated) kernel feature. This post gives a solution:

[rfkill: input handler disabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616502/rfkill-input-handler-disabled)